# CMake warning has occurred

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Straight dump of the error message:

```
 CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "interactive_markers" with any of the following names:

    interactive_markersConfig.cmake
    interactive_markers-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "interactive_markers" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "interactive_markers_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "interactive_markers" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  turtlebot3/turtlebot3_example/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318902/cmake-warning-has-occurred./) by [berlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/40532/berlin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello berlin,

usually, when you get this kind of error it means that you don't have some packages installed. In your case, it would be [interactive_markers](http://wiki.ros.org/interactive_markers).

You can easily install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-interactive-markers
```

Also, I would suggest reading about [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html). It could save you a lot of time in the future if you understand how this command works (since it is used all the time).

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

---

Originally posted by [dljubic](https://answers.ros.org/users/32791/dljubic/) with karma: 516 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [berlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/40532/berlin/) on 2019-04-01**:
thanks,i get it